# Help with creating/drawing the PDF of signals X and Y

Tags: signal-analysis, statistics, channelcoding, random

Given is an analogue source $x$ equally distributed in the interval $[-1;+2]$.
By means of a mapping, the signal $Y$ is calculated according to
$Y = (X - 1)^3$
is generated.

1. Sketch the $PDF$ of the signal $X$, specifying characteristic values.
2. Determine the $PDF$ of the signal $Y$ and sketch it, specifying characteristic values.
3. Calculate the root mean square of the signal $Y$.
4. The signal $Y$ is now to be quantised unevenly with a resolution of $2$ bits so that the same probability applies to all quantisation levels. Determine the quantisation levels.

I know that X is a $\operatorname{rect}$ function with a width of $3$ but for the PDF the negative part should be placed on top of the right one, right?  I am a little confused. Then I wanted to start from behind with the output signal and first calculated as follows
$$P_y(x) = prob(Y = g(x) \leq y) = prob(Y = (x-1)^3 \leq y)$$
And then I came to
$$P_x(g^{-1}(y)) = prob(X \leq \sqrt[3]{y + 1})$$

The thing is that the input signal $X$ is equally distributed and therefore a $\operatorname{rect}$ of width $3$ but the problem is that there is a negative part and that is the one with $[-1|0]$ and a $PDF$ can't be negative, can it?
The other tasks somehow follow from the two.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: The first thing to do is forget all that nonsense about analogue signals; the question has nothing to do with signals.  _Sketch_ the pdf of $X$: **DO NOT** use the word _rect_ anywhere.  _Sketch_ the function $y = (x-1)^3$ on the same diagram.  What is the value of $y$ when $x=-1$? when $x=0$? when $x=1$? when $x=2$?  **Looking only at your sketch,** can you _write down_ the values of $P(Y\leq  i)$ for $i= -8, -7,  \ldots, -1, 0, 1$? I hope you don't need to use _integrals_ to express these values (which are values of the _CDF_ of $Y$).  Can you write down general formulas for $F_Y(y)$? If so,

Comment: (continued) you can differentiate the CDF formulas to arrive at the PDF of $Y$.

Comment: Your worries about negativity make no sense to me. Yes, a PDF cannot be negative, but that has nothing to do with its domain of definition, but with the values it can take.

Comment: The values for $Y=(X-1)^3$ as Dilip said, at $Y \in [-8,1]$.Then I can draw $Y$ over $X$ but that is not yet the $PDF$.  Wouldn't the $PDF$ of $Y$ then be $P_Y(y) = P_X(g^{-1}(Y)) = prob(X \leq \sqrt[3]{y} + 1)$?I then have to derive this to $y$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dy} P_y(y)$ and then arrive at $p_y(y) = \frac{1}{3}  \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{Y^2}}$. Now I can also use the values for Y, i.e. $[-8,1]$ for $p_y(y)$, right?